# .NET WindowsForm - TabPage GotFocus Event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabpage

This page indicates that TabPage has a GotFocus event, but in Visual Studio 2008 I don't see that option on the TabPage (it says it is inherited from the control, i.e. the TabControl).

What event would I use to write some code that runs each time a user clicks on a different tab?  Would I use the GotFocus of the TabControl - but in that case, when user switches to different tabs doe sthe GotFocus fire again (and pass me the tabname as a variable?)

Comment: And what did you mean with 'this page' ?

Comment: Forgot to paste the URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage_events.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tabcontrol in Windows.Forms has SelectedIndex Changed-Event and SelectedTab Property.

So registering TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged ask for the TabControl.SelectedTab is all you need.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  I was doing the TabPage Entered and having some issues.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this same problem by adding this to a `frmName_Load(object sender, System.EvenArgs e)` method.

```
this.btnInUse.Visible = false; //This sets the button to be invisible.
```

Then in the method:

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
```

I added some code to turn on the control when the tab was selected and off when it was not selected.

```
            if (this.tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name == "tabOTS")
            {
                btnInUse.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                btnInUse.Visible = false;
            }
```